# Correct way to import CSS when using SSR React?

Tags: css, reactjs

What is the correct way to import CSS files when SSR React?

This is the error I get:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| .headline {
|   color: red;
| }
```

I know it has something to do with webpack, but I've tried some CSS loaders but have not been able to make them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as in react without ssr.

Add loaders([style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) and [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)) to your webpack config:

this one for your own .css files:

```
     {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
```

and this one for the 3rd party libraries .css files:

```
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      }
```

in your react file you import it as:

```
      import './style.css';
```

dont forget to install style-loader and css-loader

```
      yarn add style-loader css-loader -D
```

Comment: Can you share a full example of this? The styles does not apply if we don't wait using async await for me.